# Heroku upload-Precompiling assets failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I need help. When trying to upload my app to heroku, I get this error, anyone know why? A few was wrong. thanks

```
       Using rake (10.1.0)
       ...
       Using tlsmail (0.0.1)
       Using uglifier (2.1.2)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       /tmp/build_e8889be5-168c-49ed-81e7-b71061fc82ee/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/smtp.rb:806: warning: already initialized constant SMTPSession
       ...
       /tmp/build_e8889be5-168c-49ed-81e7-b71061fc82ee/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:702: warning: already initialized constant APOPSession
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_e8889be5-168c-49ed-81e7-b71061fc82ee/Rakefile:7)
       ...
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
       /tmp/build_e8889be5-168c-49ed-81e7-b71061fc82ee/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_e8889be5-168c-49ed-81e7-b71061fc82ee/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `new'
       ...
       /tmp/build_e8889be5-168c-49ed-81e7-b71061fc82ee/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline):

> This means that your app is attempting to connect to the database as part of rake assets:precompile. Because the config vars are not present in the environment, we use a placeholder DATABASE_URL to satisfy Rails.

To resolve this issue, ensure that the following line appears in your `config/application.rb`:

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Once added, commit your change and redeploy to Heroku – your assets should compile without your app attempting to connect to the database, which should resolve the error you're witnessing.

**UPDATE**:

Line 46 of [your stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/9cJsejc2) includes the following message: `Devise.secret_key was not set.`

[According](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2554#issuecomment-22181594) to the author of Devise, [José Valim](https://github.com/josevalim), this issue can be resolved in the following manner:

> Please add the following to your Devise initializer:
>
> config.secret_key = '-- secret key --'

*Alternatively*, [the following solution](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2554#issuecomment-24011116) seems to have worked for a number of users:

> I went to my routes.rb file and commented out the line devise_for :installs
>
> Then I went back and reran rails generate devise:install. If that doesn't work, use the previous version of devise by editing your Gemfile's reference to Devise like this: gem 'devise', '3.0.3' and then follow the steps i mentioned above.

Comment: Hello, I did what you said and did upload, but failing that walketh in heroku.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help. I get error on heroku. to enter the page, I routed the default error page in heroku.

With config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false does not go up but the app (Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page Could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.)

No config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false, I get this error when uploading:http://pastebin.com/6DAcmNxS

Comment: Log the heroku in app: http://pastebin.com/9cJsejc2 (With config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false)

Comment: Please see my update. If this answer helps address your issue, please consider accepting it as correct: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hello, thanks for you help. If I disable the precompile, I do not compile error javascript. any idea?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what the problem is. Can you post your stack trace? Also, note that you're not disabling the precompile itself – you're disabling _initialization_ upon precompilation.

Comment: WHERE does that line go within that file?

Comment: @JGallardo: anywhere within the `class Application < Rails::Application` block.

Answer (score 18):

There a few things that solved this issue for me:

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Then, before I deployed, I compiled my assets locally and committed them:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Also, I installed this heroku add on, as was specified by the app I was launching (in my case, Spree commerce)

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp
```

And of course, make sure your database.yml file is set to use `adapter: postgresql`.

Commit all of this, push to heroku, and hopefully it will launch. If you still cannot open your app, try looking at the Heroku logs: `heroku logs -n 500`

I still needed to migrate my database with `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 3):

when you are using github and you are pushing to heroku while you are in develop branch, dont do it, go to master branch and get the updates in the develop by `git merge develop`

after that,

```
rails precompile:assets
git add -A
git commit -m "Precompile assets"
git push heroku master
```

if you want to open the website that you deployed

```
heroku open
```

if nothing shows, migrate your database first by:

```
heroku run rails db:migrate
heroku open
```

Answer (score 1):

I have failed Heroku proceompiling with same error message.
Carrierwave causes that because I have missed set up `SECRET_KEY_BASE` to Heroku setting.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.