# git push heroku master keep failing?

Tags: git, heroku, cloud9

I kept getting this error on Cloud9:

```
    remote:        /tmp/build_3d423dbc0c4cb1831da6664e6804fe37/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to daeshaun-todo-app.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/daeshaun-todo-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/daeshaun-todo-app.git'
```

I have changed everything from sqlite3 to postsql, bundle install, git add, commit and push. I deleted gemfile.lock. What did I do wrong? Feel free to ask qustions.

Comment: @JonasLochmann How would you do that?

Comment: Read the answers, the 2nd worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650621/heroku-upload-precompiling-assets-failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the answers, the 2nd worked for me: [Heroku upload-Precompiling assets failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650621/heroku-upload-precompiling-assets-failed)
It turns out it was an issue with precompiling. In `config/application.rb`

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

`