# Rails on Heroku, Pre compilation asset failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to deploy this repo  https://github.com/pyk/0xblockchain on Heroku,

When I follow the steps as suggested there, After deployment, it throw and error that twitter consumer secret key is required, So I have renamed the production.rb.sample to production.rb and added the needed twitter keys, after commuting the changes when I push the changes to heroku it throws the below error.

```
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

I tried with adding config flag of precomplied assets, but still it didnt work. 
Am I missing anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku upload-Precompiling assets failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650621/heroku-upload-precompiling-assets-failed)

Comment: No. I did all the things said there , it hasnt solved my prob yet.

Comment: In that case, you should add what you've tried to your question as well as include version information for your components and the contents of your `production.rb` files. As it is, there's not enough information to work off of.