# Precompiling assets failed when deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment, precompile-assets

I am having an issue trying to deploy a rails application. I don't know why I receive an error "Precompiling assets failed." Maybe there are problems with gems version.
Could you help.

I will reproduce the logs here:

```
Removing zeitwerk (2.4.2)
       Removing activerecord-session_store (f188efbc49a5)
       Removing letsrate (bacdc8e2f164)
       Removing validates_timeliness (af3e6ff774cc)
-----> Installing node-v16.13.1-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rush-0.6.8/lib/rush/fixnum_ext.rb:6: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
       rake aborted!
       ArgumentError: Passing string to define a callback is not supported. See the `.set_callback` documentation to see supported values.
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:282:in `build'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:678:in `block in set_callback'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:677:in `map'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:677:in `set_callback'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:231:in `after_commit'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/workless-1.1.3/lib/workless/scaler.rb:20:in `block in included'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/workless-1.1.3/lib/workless/scaler.rb:19:in `class_eval'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/workless-1.1.3/lib/workless/scaler.rb:19:in `included'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/workless-1.1.3/lib/workless/initialize.rb:2:in `include'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/workless-1.1.3/lib/workless/initialize.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/workless-1.1.3/lib/workless/railtie.rb:7:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:384:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:207:in `public_send'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:207:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:360:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:526:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_1a3940bc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

I have this error only when deploying on production. When deploying to staging, It works good.

GEMFILE:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
ruby "3.0.0"

gem "rails", "6.1.1" # "3.2.22.5"
gem "activeresource"
gem "activerecord-session_store", git: "https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store", branch: "master"
gem "sass"#, "3.4.22"#, "3.2.13"
gem "bootstrap-sass", "2.3.2"
# Encryption; I think it is for generating the password_digest so database passwords are not human readable
gem "bcrypt-ruby"#, "3.0.1"
gem "gravatar_image_tag"
gem "pg"#, "0.18.4"# "0.12.2"
gem "roo", "1.13.2"
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "rest-client"
gem "gmaps4rails"# , :git => "git://github.com/gosuto/Google-Maps-for-Rails", :branch => "1.x"
gem "geocoder"
gem "carrierwave"
gem "cloudinary"#, "1.2.2"
gem "prettyphoto-rails"
gem "best_in_place", git: "https://github.com/mmotherwell/best_in_place"# "2.1.0"
gem "letsrate", :git => "git://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate"
gem "rabl"
gem "prawn", :git => "git://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn", :tag => "0.13.2"
gem "delayed_job_active_record"
gem "recaptcha", :require => "recaptcha/rails"
gem "googlestaticmap"
gem "browser"
gem "rubyzip"#, "0.9.9"
gem "caxlsx"
gem "caxlsx_rails"
gem "jquery-datatables-rails", :git => "git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git", :ref => "3734999"
gem "bootstrap-will_paginate"#, "0.0.6"
gem "will_paginate"#, "3.0.7"
gem "acts-as-taggable-on"
gem "paper_trail"#, "~> 3.0.0"
gem "highcharts-rails", "~> 3.0.0"
gem "highstock-rails", "2.1.10"
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 6.0.0.beta2'
# Support for comments in building_tours. Provides a single Comment model that can be attached to any model(s)
gem "acts_as_commentable", git: "git://github.com/jresch-rn/acts_as_commentable"
gem "omniauth", "~> 1.2"
gem "omniauth-auth0", "~> 1.1"
gem "jwt"
gem "iconv", "~> 1.0.3"

# configurations
gem "figaro"

gem "awesome_print"

gem "test-unit"

group :development do
    gem "faker"#, "1.0.1"
    gem "annotate", "~> 2.4.1.beta"
    gem "pry"
    gem "better_errors"
    gem "binding_of_caller"
    gem "lol_dba"
    gem "rails-erd"
    #gem "therubyracer"
end

group :assets do
    gem "sass-rails"#,   "3.2.4"
    gem "coffee-rails"#, "3.2.2"
    gem "uglifier"#, "1.2.3"
end

group :test, :development do
    gem "rspec-rails", "3.5.0" # "2.10.0"
end

group :test do
    gem "capybara"#, "1.1.2"
    gem "factory_girl_rails", "1.4.0"
end

group :production do
    gem "puma"
    gem "newrelic_rpm"
    gem "workless", "~> 1.1.1"
    gem "honeybadger"
end
```

Hope you can see something that I don't! Thanks in advance

Comment: Beleive that has it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650621/heroku-upload-precompiling-assets-failed